# Adding a column to a table in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite

I've got a table in SQLite, and it already has many rows stored in it. I know realise I need another column in the table. Up to now I've just deleted the database and started again because the data has just been test data. But now the data in the database can't be deleted.

I know the query to add a column to the table, my question is what is a good way to do this so that it works for both existing users and new users? (I have updated the CREATE query I have for when the table is not found (because it's a new user or an existing user has cleared the database). It seems wrong to have an ALTER query in software that ships, and check every time. Is there some way of telling SQLite to automatically add the column if it doesn't exist during the UPDATE query I now need?

If I discover I need more columns in the future, is having a bunch of ALTER statements on startup (or somewhere?) really the best way to do it?

(If relevant this is for a node js app)

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Upgrading WinForms SQLite Database techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089540/upgrading-winforms-sqlite-database-techniques).

Comment: @CL., That seems to use things specific to WinForms.

Comment: There's nothing that you couldn't do in JS.

Comment: @CL., Sorry your right I misread it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just throw a table somewhere that marks what version of your database it is, and check that to determine if an update is needed. Either that or if you have a table already where there's always going to be just one record in it add a new field 'DatabaseVersion' to it.

So for example if you check the version number, and find it's a version 1 database when the newest version should be version 3, you know which updates to perform on it.

Comment: This kind of seems like something the database should do, (at least add columns if they don't exist already)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PRAGMA user_version` to store the version number of the database and check if the database needs to be updated.